# How to find the most recently edited files

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

How can I find the most recently modified *.ipynb files in the subtree starting from the current directory? Ideally I would like a sorted list with the most recently modified ones shown first.

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 and am happy to use GNU tools.

Answer (score 2):

Like this with [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```
(shopt -s globstar; ls -lt **/*.ipynb)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use find with -newermt option as below.

The below command finds the files modified in the last 24 hours.

```
find . -type f -newermt "-24 hours"
```

Similarly,

```
find . -type f -newermt "-10 minutes" 
find . -type f -newermt "1 day ago" 
find . -type f -newermt "yesterday"
```